# ¿Como salir de un proyecto en Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Estoy intentando salir de un proyecto el cual me asignaron un Rol en firebase y no encuentro una opción similar a "Salir del proyecto" o "dejar proyecto", alguien podría guiarme?

Al parecer sólo lo puede hacer el administrador, pero no estoy seguro. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En la Configuración del proyecto, Usuarios y Permisos. Ahí tienes la opción que necesitas, pero depende del rol que el propietario te asignó. Debes tener el rol como propietario para poder. Saludos.